# I am trying to decode and extract octet string from the extension of X509Certificate, but I did not get any valid string

Tags: x509certificate, x509, der, asn.1, devicecheck

I have been trying to decode the octet string as per steps mentioned in
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicecheck/validating_apps_that_connect_to_your_server?language=objc
Here is what I have tried:

```
        X509Certificate cert1 = getParentCertificate(new String(decodedCredCert));
        System.out.println(cert1);
        cert1.checkValidity(); // verify against apple app attest root ca
        byte[] ext = cert1.getExtensionValue("1.2.840.113635.100.8.2");
        ASN1InputStream bIn = new ASN1InputStream(ext);
        ASN1Primitive obj = bIn.readObject();
        ASN1OctetString string = (ASN1OctetString) obj;
        byte[] octs = string.getOctets();
        ASN1InputStream dIn = new ASN1InputStream(octs);
        String octetString = ASN1Dump.dumpAsString(dIn.readObject());
```

I got the output as: "[[1]#8333585e692916d8cbcdce3c6aa2bd71617d54fed758957cfd6b50a2093fd506]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Ios [AppAttestation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicecheck/validating_apps_that_connect_to_your_server?language=objc), follow as below to get the extension value and it's corresponding octet string. As mentioned in that page,

> Obtain the value of the credCert extension with OID
> 1.2.840.113635.100.8.2, which is a DER-encoded ASN.1 sequence. Decode the sequence and extract the single octet string that it contains.

Here is the sample code:

```
byte[] oidValue = credCert.getExtensionValue(ooid);
DEROctetString envelope = (DEROctetString) new ASN1InputStream(oidValue).readObject();
DLSequence sequence = (DLSequence) new ASN1InputStream(envelope.getOctetStream()).readObject();
DLTaggedObject taggedObject = (DLTaggedObject) sequence.getObjectAt(0);
DEROctetString taggedObjectOctet = (DEROctetString) taggedObject.getObject();
log.debug("Octet String : {}", taggedObjectOctet.getOctets());
```

Answer (score 1):

"Octet string" is just a spec phrase that modern languages call "byte array".  You've extracted the value as of `octs`, and should compare that value to whatever nonce you're supposed to compare it against.